# TinyMCE Django Framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, tinymce

I am using the TinyMCE editor for the admin part of my website. The editor seems like it is installed correctly but after saving a post and displaying it on the main page it shows the raw html instead of rendering it.

More specifically it shows

[image]

If it helps I used HTMLField in the model

Answer (score 0):

when you want to display html stored in a model you need to mark it as safe (if it is of course) for it to bypass the `XSS` protection
see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#safe

> Marks a string as not requiring further HTML escaping prior to output.
>   When autoescaping is off, this filter has no effect.

example for your template

```
{{ model.attribute|safe}}
```